# How to add a class to a specific link in a link list in Shopify?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I need to add a class to a specific link in a link list. The link i need to target will always be the word 'shop'. I tried applying the following to the `<a>` link within my link list but it doesn't seem to be working..

```
<a href="{{ link.url }}" class="{% if link.title contains 'shop' %}site-nav-shop {% endif %}site-nav__link">{{ link.title }}</a>
```

Any ideas how I can get this to work!?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and got it working in my test site. A couple of things to check:

1. It's case sensitive, so check that your link titles contain 'shop' and not 'Shop' or something else.
2. Make sure you've got your code in the right place. E.g. I noticed in the Timber theme there is a regular site nav and a mobile site nav. Check you're not adding the class to the wrong `<a>...</a>`.

Comment: It turned out to be the case sensitive issue, changed it to 'Shop' and got it working. Thanks for your help!